# passing url as parameter in javascript is not calling the function

Tags: javascript

```
<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="openWindow(2,1,4326,http://www.../images/icon_tree1.gif);">Edit Asset Info</a>
```

Function openWindow is not called and I am see the folowing error on console

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` and

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

This is the actual code I am using

```
return "<a href='javascript:void();' onclick='openWindow(" 2 "," + 1 + "," + 4326 + "," + symbolurl + ");'>Edit Asset Info</a>";
```

Comment: `http://www.unm.edu/~jka/courses/images/icon_tree1.gif` is not a JavaScript string literal. Try again. (Hint: compare `x` with `'x'`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URL address is a string, so you should surround it with quotes:

```
... onclick="openWindow(2,1,4326,'http://www.../images/icon_tree1.gif');" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a string to the onclick handler `onclick="openWindow(1, 2, 3, 'http://...')"`
Some other comments:
1, If your anchor doesn't actually take the user anywhere, consider not to use `<a>` rather than `href="javascript:void();"`
2, try not to mix javascript with html. so link your event handler to the DOM element in a `<script>` tag.